# rsync does not preserve timestamp after failure

Tags: rsync

I use the following option to synchronize to a btrs remote server.

```
rsync -aRrzu --inplace --delete -vv --files-from XXX
```

When the rsync fail (Ctr+C, very long network outage, ...) file that being transferred has its modification time set to the current time on the remote server and not the source modification time. Modification time is correctly set for files which transfer succeed.

As a consequence, as I am using `--inplace` (which implies `--partial`), the incomplete remote file is not deleted and appears to be newer than the source. So that re-running rsync does not synchronize this incomplete file.

Is there any way to enforce mtime to be set before transferring files ?
`--checksum` may solve the issue, but has I deal with very large file (20GB), I would like to avoid this.

Comment: Welcome to this site! Maybe take a look at the option `--size-only` as mentioned in this question https://serverfault.com/questions/344731/rsync-copying-over-timestamps-only

Comment: From man : `-t, --times  preserve modification times`

Comment: @SivaPrasath thank you, but the `--times` switch is implied by the `-a` which I use

Comment: @MrShunz good workaround to the use of the `--checksum` option. But it may cause issue with `--inplace` when file is being modified such that size has not changed before the failure.

Comment: Well, that's true, so probably a two pass rsync would do, first with `--size-only` to resume updating those partial files, then a normal pass to update the remaining files based on timestamps.

Comment: Why are you using `--inplace`? Removing that will fix your problem.

Comment: @wurtel you are right, actually `--inplace` cause this issue. However I am syncing to a btrfs based filesystem in order to make use of builting snapshot. Nonetheless btrfs requires `--inplace` switch to achieve space efficient management / incremental snapshots.

Comment: OK, the COW of btrfs is a good reason. Using `-u` is also unusual, removing that would also help. Note that `-a` implies `-r` so you can leave the `r` out.

Comment: @wurtel In fact, `-u` would do the job. However, I would like to keep synchronization check based on times. I think that with `--inplace` it is impossible.
`-a` implies `'-r` unless you use `--files-from` :) the delights of rsync options.